# PDF printer that let me append to last PDF or create new PDF

Tags: pdf, printing

The current PDF program I am using is eCopy which is part of our office's printer/scanner package. It is amazing but has stopped working for some reason (support ticket open with them). In the mean time, I am looking for a replacement or fall back program.

What I need it to do is work as a printer in any program but it has to allow me to either create a new document or amend it to an already open document. I can't use a program that makes you save it first and then join the two documents together. That is too much saving and opening files. Currently when I print to eCopy, a box pops up asking me if I would like to add it to the current document or create a new one. If I create a new one, a new file opens but I do not have to save it first, I can do that later if needed. I am an accountant who works from home so everything I do is paperless.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that you can still merge PDFs if you don't find a solution http://www.wikihow.com/Merge-PDF-Files

Comment: We are looking for the same solution. We were using FoxIt and loved the features. FoxIt 'upgraded' to a new version and the append feature went away. (What in the heck?) It has been a big issue with productivity.

Answer (score 1):

See if [FreePDF](http://freepdfxp.de/index_en.html) works for you. That's what the company I work for uses in its enterprise workstations and laptops.

When you print something to PDF, it asks you whether you want to save it to disk right away or add it to another PDF. In the latter case, the UI closes but basically sits there waiting for you to print another file. Then when you save the last file, both files will be printed in a single PDF file.

Hope it helps. If so, let me know!

Answer (score 1):

If a commercial application is an option for you, then try with [Amyuni PDF Converter Desktop Edition](http://www.amyuni.com/en/enduser/pdfconverterend/). The default "Save as" dialog has a checkbox for selecting an existing file and concatenating the new PDF to it.

[image]

The application is a virtual printer driver, certified by Microsoft for all versions of Windows from Vista to Windows 8.1. You can evaluate the application for free and see if it meets your needs.

*Disclaimer: I work for Amyuni Technologies*